# passing php array to javascript variable, then to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, variables

I realize this has been asked numerous times here, but I just can't figure it out. I'm certain it is simple, but I've been banging my head a little. I have search results that are php arrays, displayed in a jquery window. I need to eventually get them back to the server, but first need to pass them to jquery variables. This is where I am stuck.

You will see I have made an attempt to via $book_title, trying to pass that to a jquery variable "title"

```
<script>
      $(function() { 
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        height: 550, width: 450});
        $( ".btn" ).click(function(){
        //assign values to each variable
        //var title = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var title = <?php echo json_encode($book_title);?>;
        var author = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var published = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var description = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var pages = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var publisher = $("#returnvalues").val();
        var ISBN = $("#returnvalues").val();
       //book_title = $item['volumeInfo']['title'];
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'book-meta.php',
         dataType: 'json',
         //assign values to the variables to be passed to the server via data
         data: { title : title, author : author, published : published, 
         description : description, pages : pages, publisher : publisher, ISBN : ISBN},
         success: function(data)
             {
             //alert(data);
             //identify the variables for unique handing on the server side
             $("input[name='bbp_topic_title']").val(data.title);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field1']").val(data.author);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field2']").val(data.published);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field3']").val(data.description);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field4']").val(data.pages);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field5']").val(data.publisher);
             $("input[name='bbp_extra_field6']").val(data.ISBN);
             //$("#displayResults").html(data);
             },
             error: function(errorThrown){
             alert('error');
             }
             });
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );  
      });
      });
      </script>  
            <strong><p style="font-size: 16px; text-align: center";>Top 10 Results for &quot;<?php echo @$_POST['q']; ?>&quot;</p></strong> 
        <strong><p style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center";>choose a book to select as your topic</p></strong>&nbsp;
        <table style="width:400px">
        <col width="325">
        <col width="75">
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($data['items'] as $item) { $i++; ?>     
                  <tr>
            <td>
                       <strong><u><div style="font-size: 14px";><?php printf($item['volumeInfo']['title'])?></u></div></strong>
                         <strong>Author: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0])?><br />
                         <strong>Published: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publishedDate']); ?><br />                       
               <strong>Page(s): </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['pageCount']); ?><br />
                         <strong>Publisher: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['publisher']); ?><br />
                         <strong>Category: </strong><?php printf( strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['printType']).', '.strtolower($item['volumeInfo']['categories'][0])); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <strong>ISBN: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['industryIdentifiers'][0]['identifier']); ?></td>
            <td><p><input type="submit" method="post" name="selectbook" value="Select" class="btn" id="returnvalues" /></p>
            <img src="<?php printf( rawurldecode($item['volumeInfo']['imageLinks']['smallThumbnail'])); ?>" />
                    </td>
            <tr><td style="width:420px"><p><strong>Description: </strong><?php printf( $item['volumeInfo']['description']); ?><br /></p></td>
            <?php $book_title=$item['volumeInfo']['title'];
            //$book_meta=array($item['volumeInfo']['title']=>"$book_title",$item['volumeInfo']['authors'][0]=>"$book_author");
            //print(json_encode($book_meta));
```

Any help is appreciated. If this gets marked as a duplicate question, please also give this newbie some specific direction. Thanks.

Comment: Does $book_title contains array or string of characters(any name) or array of names?

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out! Thanks to XQDev and Uttara for the help! I had to create a separate script, within the loop where my php results are displayed. In this separate script I declare my javascript variables only.

```
<script>
var title = <?php echo json_encode($book_title); ?>;
</script>
```

Issue is resolved! Hopefully this thread will help someone in the future with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

`var title = "<?php echo $book_title; ?>"` could cause your wanted result.

The result can be checked by using `alert(title)` after the assignment.

Your variable are no "jQuery Variables", by the way. They are ordinary Javascript variables. But you pass and access them by using jQuery methods.

But: Your way, in case $book_title contains a string, should be fine, too.. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Thanks. This has not accomplished the job, but perhaps you and @Uttara are getting me close. I did change the title as you suggested. I am also using `alert(title)`. With your suggestion, I see a blank return, with @Uttara's suggestion, I get a "null" response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to assign php array to javascript variable then do this

```
var title = <?php echo json_encode($book_title); ?>;
```

considering that your $book_title is an array

```
Eg: <?php 
   $book_title = array('one', 'two');
?>

javascript: title = ['one', 'two']
```

Comment: So far your suggestion does not work. I wonder if it has to do with this line of code: `$("input[name='bbp_topic_title']").val(data.title);`  This is how I pass the variable to the server. Perhaps that needs to change? On the other hand, I am using `alert(title)` and I am getting a "null" response.

Comment: After some debugging tonight, I have learned that my problem is as such: The variable `$book_title=$item['volumeInfo']['title'];` is not getting to the javascript variable `var title = "<?php echo json_encode($book_title); ?>";` I know that `$book_title` has a value. So I believe the problem is that I cannot get `$book_title` from the server side to the client side. Any suggestions?

Comment: As long as you can echo $book_title anywhere on your document, you can pass it as value to a Javascript variable. Before the document becomes passed to the client, your var title = "<?php echo json_encode($book_title); ?>"; becomes a simple var title = "yourtitle"; You should see that, if you open the HTML source.

Comment: @XQDev, thanks for your continued help. I checked the HTML source, and it is showing: var title = "Null"; I have been exhaustively searching, and many people say to do exactly what Uttara suggested. So I am at a loss

Comment: When I set `$book_title = "Test";` and place it above the script, everything works as advertised. However, placing `$book_title = $item['volumeInfo']['title'];` above the script still returns a null value to `title`. If I place `$book_title = "Test";` below the table (where $book_title is located in my code above), then null is the result of `title`. I have even made $book_title a global variable. Anyone have any ideas? This is frustrating.